# Delete temporary files created by acessing zip entries before the JVM terminates

Tags: java, zip

I am working on a web application which envolves unzipping lots of files. This leads to a lot of zip entries being read and a lot of files being created in the system's temporary directory (the one that you obtain from the system property 'java.io.tmpdir').

This is normally not an issue since these files (being temporary) are correctly deleted when the JVM terminates. The problem arises when the server in which the application is deployed hasn't been restarted for a while. The temporary files just keep building up and filling the server's disk.

What I wanted to do here would be to delete the temporary files that are generated from the zip after each zip file is processed (I have to maintain the zip file itself, so my objective is not to delete those).

The code snippet that handles the messages is the following:

```
    ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(file);

    try {
        Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
        while(entries.hasMoreElements()){
            ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();

            InputStream in = zipFile.getInputStream(zipEntry);

            try{

                //do stuff with the inputstream

                in.close();
                in = null;
            }
            finally {
                if(in != null){
                    in.close();
                }
                zipEntry = null;
            }
        }
    } finally {
        zipFile.close();
    }
```

Is there any way in Java to access and delete these temporary files? Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I may be missing the point but why do you need to create temporary files at all after opening the zip file?

Comment: In your example, you don't create any temporary files.  Can you show us how they are being used and why?

Comment: I am not explicitly creating a temporary file, the JVM does that automatically when you read a zip file. For each entry that you read, a temporary file is created in the system's temporary folder.

Comment: maybe you can try to use "ZipInputStream" instead of "ZipFile". I think those temporary files are created due to caching of the zip entries (when using ZipFile class) and maybe its not best to try and delete them. Please check this link and you will find about the differences between the classes in in one note: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/